# Cfdocument being served by server despite being in cfsavecontent

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-8, cfdocument

It seems that when I use the `<cfsavecontent>` tag, the output of that is being served by the server (without the variable being outputted), which, to me, kind of  defeats the purpose of `<cfsavecontent>`.

If this is important: my application uses ColdSpring, ModelGlue and Transfer ORM.

Here's my example code in a function:

```
<cfsavecontent variable="testvar">
<cfinclude template="test.cfm" />
</cfsavecontent>
<cfreturn testvar>
```

And the template:

```
<cfdocument format="PDF" pagetype="A4" orientation="portrait" unit="cm">
<cfoutput>
<!--- PDF content here --->
</cfoutput>
</cfdocument>
```

The PDF content is being parsed by my browser (Google Chrome), while the view hasn't even been loaded in. How can I best prevent this from happening?

Just to clarify: I am not outputting the `#testvar#` variable yet in this code, though it seems it loads the template in the browser anyways.

Comment: What are you attempting to do with the cfreturn tag?

Comment: Quoting my question: "Here's my example code in a **function**:"

Comment: Oops, I missed that part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I also needed to make multiple PDF documents merge, I ended up doing the following. Many thanks to Adam Cameron for providing the solution to my initial issue.

- In the template file, I use the `<cfdocument>` tag with the `name` attribute to save the PDF in a variable (thanks to Adam Cameron for this)
- Then, I store all the PDF documents in an array in their binary format
- In my view, I merge the PDF documents together by using `<cfpdf>`'s `merge` action, and using a cfloop, to loop over the array, inside it.
- Finally, I display the content by using `<cfcontent>` and using the variable attribute with `toBinary(myPdf)`

This got me to where I am.

Answer (score 8):

To achieve what you're trying to do, should you not simply be using the `name` attribute of [`<cfdocument>`](http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/Tags_d-e_05.html) to put the PDF data into a variable, instead of trying to `<cfsavecontent>` it?

Disclosure: I've never used `<cfdocument>` for anything other than proof-of-concept code and testing, but that's what I'm inferring from the docs.

Comment: I *have* used `<cfdocument>` quite a bit and Adam is right. `<cfsavecontent>` is for storing text. If you want to generate the PDF binary but save it for later processing rather than outputting straight to the browser, then just use the `name` attribute in the same way you'd use the `variable` attribute of `<cfsavecontent>`.

Comment: Sorry for the late response, but how would I then output it? I tried the following: `<cfheader name="Content-Disposition" value="inline; filename=#filename#"><cfcontent type="application/x-pdf"><cfoutput>#pdfData#</cfoutput></cfcontent>` but this gives a "corrupt" pdf (Adobe Reader cannot open it). I verified that the variable does indeed contain binary data.

Comment: Never mind actually, I know now that I need to put it inside the `<cfcontent>` tag. Now, how would I put multiple variables with PDF content into one PDF? (I have an array with all the PDF content. I tried doing a cfloop and doing cfcontent on each of them, but that of course doesn't work, as cfcontent blocks any other output (so incl. other cfcontent's))

Comment: That's a completely different question mate, which you should raise separately.

Answer (score 1):

cfinclude will process the test.cfm page, and the way you configured cfdocument will cause "opening" of pdf document in your browser.
You can prevent openning of this file by saving file on the disc:

```
<cfdocument format="PDF" pagetype="A4" orientation="portrait" unit="cm" filename ="test.pdf" overwrite ="yes">
```

But this will not prevent execution of cfinclude in the cfcontent tag, it will just prevent opening in the browser.

You can observe cfinclude as request to the server, it will always be executed.

The solution would be to invoke request on test.cfm file which contains cfdocument in the moment that you actually want to generate pdf.

Example: Use javascript on client to invoke report service which will generate and pop out the screen with pdf report.

Hope this helps.